# Combine data from two post requests

Tags: go, redis

I have a Rest API that gets the POST requests, data and images comes in two different requests.

```
/v1/photo # multipart/form-data
/v1/data # json
```

I'm trying to merge values into Redis

```
# Save photo
HSET photo:1.jpg file_name 9f7a6775-3815-4d20-affa-e81bc9c4293b
SADD have:uuid photo:1.jpg
HSET photo:2.jpg file_name fcb7db2d-159e-4d0e-b884-ca455bd6f4a5
SADD have:uuid photo:2.jpg

# Save data
HSET photo:1.jpg data JSONsring
SADD have:data photo:1.jpg
HSET photo:2.jpg data JSONsring
SADD have:data photo:2.jpg
```

Now I need to get all the combined data (In order to save them to another database). 
I can use `sinter` to get keys.

```
SINTER have:uuid have:data
```

But i need JSON and UUID.

How to make it as quickly and with the minimum spent resources?

Comment: Why not just update the fields as you get them, and throw an appropriate error in the process that's responsible for pulling that data out of redis?

Comment: So simple. =) Thank you so much! This should work!

Comment: Did it work? If so @william.taylor.09 should turn his comment into an answer so that you can accept his answer and close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of ensuring this has a marked answer, I'll take the advice of @reticentroot and format the comment into an answer.

It would be more idiomatic for your POST endpoint to accept the request regardless of whether a corresponding /v1/photo or /v1/data entry has been created. The process that's interfacing with these pieces of data could easily check whether it has both pieces of data, and act accordingly.